# c++11 std::async doesn't work in mingw

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, mingw, stdasync

Running this code from Herb Sutter's [presentation](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Lang-NEXT/Lang-NEXT-2012/-Not-Your-Father-s-C-).  This works fine in linux under gcc 4.6.3.  I'm thinking that future.h isn't supported in mingw, but the error is really hard to understand!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <future>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

string flip( string s ) {
  reverse( begin(s), end(s) );
  return s;
}

int main() {
  vector<future<string>> v;

  v.push_back( async([]{ return flip(" ,olleH"); }) );
  v.push_back( async([]{ return flip(".gnaL"); }) );
  v.push_back( async([]{ return flip("\n!TXEN"); }) );

  for( auto& e: v ) {
    cout << e.get();
  }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -std=c++0x -pthread swap.cpp
swap.cpp: In function 'int main()':
swap.cpp:17:51: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'std::__async_sfinae_helper<main()::<lambda()>, main()::<lambda()> >::type {aka class std::future<std::basic_string<char> >}'
In file included from swap.cpp:4:0:
c:\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/future:111:11: error: declaration of 'std::__async_sfinae_helper<main()::<lambda()>, main()::<lambda()> >::type {aka class std::future<std::basic_string<char> >}'
swap.cpp:18:49: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'std::__async_sfinae_helper<main()::<lambda()>, main()::<lambda()> >::type {aka class std::future<std::basic_string<char> >}'
In file included from swap.cpp:4:0:
c:\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/future:111:11: error: declaration of 'std::__async_sfinae_helper<main()::<lambda()>, main()::<lambda()> >::type {aka class std::future<std::basic_string<char> >}'
swap.cpp:19:51: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'std::__async_sfinae_helper<main()::<lambda()>, main()::<lambda()> >::type {aka class std::future<std::basic_string<char> >}'
In file included from swap.cpp:4:0:
c:\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/future:111:11: error: declaration of 'std::__async_sfinae_helper<main()::<lambda()>, main()::<lambda()> >::type {aka class std::future<std::basic_string<char> >}'
swap.cpp:22:14: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class std::future<std::basic_string<char> >'
In file included from swap.cpp:4:0:
c:\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/future:111:11: error: declaration of 'class std::future<std::basic_string<char> >'
In file included from c:\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:68:0,
                 from c:\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:41,
                 from c:\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/ios:41,
                 from c:\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/ostream:40,
                 from c:\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/iostream:40,
                 from swap.cpp:1:
c:\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h: In instantiation of '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>& __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator++() [with _Iterator = std::future<std::basic_string<char> >*; _Container = std::vector<std::future<std::basic_string<char> > >; __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container> = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::future<std::basic_string<char> >*, std::vector<std::future<std::basic_string<char> > > >]':
swap.cpp:21:17:   required from here
c:\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h:750:2: error: cannot increment a pointer to incomplete type 'std::future<std::basic_string<char> >'
In file included from c:\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/vector:65:0,
                 from swap.cpp:2:
c:\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h: In instantiation of 'std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::~_Vector_base() [with _Tp = std::future<std::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::future<std::basic_string<char> > >]':
c:\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:247:15:   required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector() [with _Tp = std::future<std::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::future<std::basic_string<char> > >]'
swap.cpp:15:26:   required from here
c:\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:161:9: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class std::future<std::basic_string<char> >'
In file included from swap.cpp:4:0:
c:\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/future:111:11: error: declaration of 'class std::future<std::basic_string<char> >'
In file included from c:\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/vector:63:0,
                 from swap.cpp:2:
c:\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of 'void std::_Destroy(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _ForwardIterator = std::future<std::basic_string<char> >*]':
c:\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/bits/stl_construct.h:155:7:   required from 'void std::_Destroy(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_T2>&) [with _ForwardIterator = std::future<std::basic_string<char> >*; _Tp = std::future<std::basic_string<char> >]'
c:\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:403:9:   required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::~vector() [with _Tp = std::future<std::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::future<std::basic_string<char> > >]'
swap.cpp:15:26:   required from here
c:\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/bits/stl_construct.h:128:7: error: invalid use of incomplete type '_Value_type {aka class std::future<std::basic_string<char> >}'
In file included from swap.cpp:4:0:
c:\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/future:111:11: error: declaration of '_Value_type {aka class std::future<std::basic_string<char> >}'
c:\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/future: At global scope:
c:\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/future:187:5: error: 'typename std::__async_sfinae_helper<typename std::decay<_Func>::type, _Fn, _Args ...>::type std::async(_Fn&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Fn = main()::<lambda()>; _Args = {}; typename std::__async_sfinae_helper<typename std::decay<_Func>::type, _Fn, _Args ...>::type = std::future<std::basic_string<char> >]', declared using local type 'main()::<lambda()>', is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
c:\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/future:187:5: error: 'typename std::__async_sfinae_helper<typename std::decay<_Func>::type, _Fn, _Args ...>::type std::async(_Fn&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Fn = main()::<lambda()>; _Args = {}; typename std::__async_sfinae_helper<typename std::decay<_Func>::type, _Fn, _Args ...>::type = std::future<std::basic_string<char> >]', declared using local type 'main()::<lambda()>', is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
c:\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/future:187:5: error: 'typename std::__async_sfinae_helper<typename std::decay<_Func>::type, _Fn, _Args ...>::type std::async(_Fn&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Fn = main()::<lambda()>; _Args = {}; typename std::__async_sfinae_helper<typename std::decay<_Func>::type, _Fn, _Args ...>::type = std::future<std::basic_string<char> >]', declared using local type 'main()::<lambda()>', is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
```

I'm using GCC 4.7 in windows.

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=c:\mingw64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.7.0/configure --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-targets=all --disable-multilib --enable-64bit --prefix=/mingw64 --with-sysroot=/mingw64 --disable-shared --enable-static --disable-nls --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --disable-win32-registry --without-dwarf2 --enable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-languages=c,ada,lto,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --enable-libgomp --enable-lto --enable-libssp -enable-gnattools --disable-bootstrap --with-gcc --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-stabs --enable-interwork --with-mpfr-include=/home/beta/gcc-build/../gcc-4.7.0/mpfr/src --with-mpfr-lib=/home/beta/gcc-build/mpfr/src/.libs
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.7.0 (GCC)
```

Comment: If you GCC is 4.6.3, it shouldn't be picking up a 4.7 template library.

Comment: What is the compiler version in mingw?

Comment: i'm using 4.7 in windows. edited question with gcc -v. thanks.

Comment: Works for my GCC 4.7.0 on Mac.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's a windows platform thing, but I'm not sure since the error message is so opaque.

Comment: To be clear, it is not windows but MinGW that is buggy there. The OS have nothing to do with the compiler. Maybe changing of gcc port would  work, or maybe just trying with clang instead of gcc.

Comment: Right. I meant GCC on windows platform.  VS11 beta supports this program.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe it's easier for me to interpret because I wrote that code, but it's not so hard, just look at the first line of the error output:

```
swap.cpp:22:14: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class std::future<std::basic_string<char> >'
```

That's telling you that `std::future` is an incomplete type, i.e. it is declared but not defined.  The next line tells you exactly where it's declared (then all the other errors are caused by trying to use that incomplete type in different ways.)

If you look in GCC's `<future>` header you'll see that the types are declared near the top, but then the definitions are dependent on this preprocessor condition:

```
#if defined(_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS) && defined(_GLIBCXX_USE_C99_STDINT_TR1) \
  && (ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE > 1)
```

If you compile some simple tests with those macros you'll find out that `_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS` is not defined, and that's because your `gcc -v` shows

```
Thread model: win32
```

No one has provided the necessary code to make the C++11 thread features work on Windows yet.

Making `<future>` work would be harder, but it's not actually that difficult to enable `<thread>` and `<mutex>` but no one has stepped up to do the work yet.  Yesterday I posted some ideas for how to enable the C++11 thread features for the win32 thread model: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2012-05/msg00020.html

Comment: This still doesn't work as of 2015, with cryptic errors again.  Does `std::async` work under any other threading model flavour of MinGW-w64 ?   (if so, that would be somewhat puzzling as all models must boil down to Windows API thread calls at some point -- but also useful info as I could then get the other flavour)

Answer (score 3):

**The special MinGW build called 'MinGW builds' does provide C++11 support via gcc including *async*, *thread*, *future* and friends**

*(this seconds the down-voted answer by IcemanX)*

It has moved to http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/

As Jonathan Wakely points out (correctly and authoritatively) the issue with other versions of GCC is that they do not provide support for *pthreads*, but MinGW-builds do. A solution using windows threads would probably be better but is currently not available.

I wrote a detailed **installation and setup instruction for MinGW build+eclipse**, here: http://scrupulousabstractions.tumblr.com/post/36441490955/eclipse-mingw-builds

Comment: MinGW-builds is not the official release of MinGW: maybe you want to clarify this. Your title may make people misunderstand. But the information useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do not know if std::async has valid implementation ( if at all ) but the std::thread works with MinGW/GCC 4.7 version, available at the project site http://code.google.com/p/mingw-builds/

hope this helps

Comment: yeah, i'm not really looking to implement anything specific here; just to test out c++11 features in mingw.  thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

Standard MinGW library & compiler does not support `std::async(*args)`

But there is a modified version of MinGW which has the same features as the original one, which is: [TDM-GCC MinGW](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download)

It is free for downloading and has regular updates. Also, it supports *32 & 64 bits* also for **compiling code.**

Hope it helps ^^

Answer (score 0):

Just download MinGW installer from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) and install with configuration posix thread.

[image]

If you already have old MinGW installed then edit you environment variable so that newly installed MinGW is used.