# Which Windows compilers support <future> class

Tags: c++, windows, qt, c++11, future

I was trying to run the [test code](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/future/) for the `future` class on Windows but I had several problems. First I tried using the default compiler of Code::Blocks which in my case is MinGW 4.7.1 obtaining the error

```
error: variable 'std::future<bool> fut' has initializer but incomplete type|
```

As suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209871/c11-stdasync-doesnt-work-in-mingw) it seems that

> No one has provided the necessary code to make the C++11 thread features work on Windows yet.

Since the question was from 2012 I gave it a try with more recent compilers. I had no luck using both MinGW 4.8.1 and MinGW 5.1

Surprisingly, when I tried the default compiler for Qt Creator which in my case is MinGW 4.9.1 it worked fine.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

`MinGW != MinGW`

Multiple GCC-for-Windows projects exist, like [MinGW](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/), [MinGW](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) and [MinGW](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/), with different development states (last one supports the most).

Future objects are part of concurrency which got attention in GCC 4.8 and MSVC 11.

C::B uses TDM-GCC, QT Creator MinGW64 - that's the point.

Comment: Pretty courageous post :)  There are some MinGW enthusiasts that are pretty ticked-off at the fork.