# Coudn't run code used std::async on GCC 5.3.0

Tags: c++11, gcc, pthreads, mingw, stdasync

I was practicing `std::asyn` function that introduced in c++11, I wrote a simple example

```
#include<future>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void check()
{
    cout<<"some"<<endl;
}
 int main()
 {
    auto p=std::async(std::launch::async,check);
    p.get();
 }
```

Yes very simple to start off with and i am compiling it using GCC 5.3.0

`g++ -std=c++11 practise.cpp -lpthread`

and the error

```
practise.cpp: In function 'int main()':
practise.cpp:13:47: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class std::future<int>'
     auto p=std::async(std::launch::async,chech);
                                               ^
In file included from practise.cpp:1:0:
C:/Program Files/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/future:115:11: note: declaration of 'class std::future<int>'
     class future;
           ^
```

Am i missing anything? is the way i linked lpthread is ok? i am on windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem looks very similar to the one from this SO:

[c++11 std::async doesn't work in mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209871/c11-stdasync-doesnt-work-in-mingw)

You should check what `gcc -v` returns for 'Thread model:'. In above SO it returns win32 - and quite possibly mingw still does not support async/future in this mode.

In my mingw installation - also 5.3.0, I have `Thread model: posix`. I checked the exact same compile flags as yours and your example always compiles fine.

So my suggestion is for you to first check thread model with gcc -v, if its non posix, then reinstall mingw with posix threads. You choose threads model when running mingw-w64-install.exe installer/

Comment: "https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/5.3.0/threads-posix/seh/" this could be the right package for me