# MinGW -- incomplete type when using std::future<void>

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, mingw32

I've written code that compiles, and executes on Linux without issue using gcc. However, the same code doesn't appear to be compiling on Windows using MinGW. Here is the code snippet:

```
std::future<void> gameTimer;
```

This is the error that I get:

```
In file included from ..\prohect\main.cpp:1:0: field 'gameTimer' has incomplete type 'std::future<void>
    std::future<void> gameTimer;
                      ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from ..\project\project.h:12:0, from ..\project\main.cpp:1: declaration of 'class std::future<void>'
    class future;
          ^~~~~~
```

Am I missing something from the MinGW installation?

Comment: What is your MinGW/GCC/libstdc++ version? [Possibly relevant](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64735)

Comment: The version currently installed is 6.3.0-1

Comment: You most likely need to include some header file. Incomplete type means that you only said that this class exist but you have not actually implemented it so there is something like `class A;` instead of `class A {....}`. Maybe you need to include  future `#include <future>`.

Comment: The header is already included, otherwise it wouldn't have compiled on Linux

Comment: @humroben no, that does **not** follow.

Comment: This is because MinGW does not support future as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10471936).